# Jenkins multi-branch pipeline workspace location: shell versus Groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Summary:** When using parallel builds the workspace path differs in Groovy compared to shell. How can I get the actual workspace from the DSL or Groovy?

**Details:**

Our workspace is defined via `ws( '/path/to/workspace' )`.

I'm attempting to use a relative path, simply `package.json`, to open that file in the current directory which is usually the workspace root. When run as shell, `sh 'jq -r ".version" package.json'` it works fine and I can read `package.json` without any issues.

However using Groovy:

```
def version = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( new File( "package.json" ).text )[ 'version' ]
```

Note `new File( "package.json" )` then it fails with claiming `$WORKSPACE/package.json` does not exist. Despite our setting the workspace above with `ws` I can see it ends up being something like */path/to/workspace/my_job-SOMERANDOMCHARS...* not the directory specified in `ws`.

I understand that in parallel workloads we need to make the workspace unique so this is not unexpected. But how should I determine the workspace from Groovy? Or is the expectation always to break out to shell that actually runs on a Node?

**Update: More context**

Some more info on how this is being used. Our Groovy (not declarative) pipeline does something along these lines:

```
stage('tests') {
  parallel(
    'Unit Tests': {
       node('unitNode') {
         ws('/path/to/workspace') {
           new file("${env.WORKSPACE}/package.json") // does not work 
           sh 'cat $WORKSPACE/package.json' // works OK
         }
       }
    },
    'E2E Tests': {
       node('e2eNode') {
         ws('/path/to/workspace') {
           new file("${env.WORKSPACE}/package.json") // does not work 
           sh 'cat $WORKSPACE/package.json' // works OK
         }
       }
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to access files relative to the workspace is to use [readFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) or, more handily in this case, [readJSON](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readjson-code-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace). This works for me and I don't have to care about the actual absolute path of the workspace.

There are also other readXXXX methods such as readYAML, readManifest, readMavenPom, etc. See the [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps) docs for the full list and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption about how you are using ws(). Without seeing your actual code, your description implies you are doing something like this:

```
ws(/new/path/to/workspace) {
    sh "cat package.json"
}

def version = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( new File( "package.json" ).text )[ 'version' ]
```

If this is how you are doing it, then the workspace will no longer be applicable outside of the ws{} block.

The path that you show ( /path/to/workspace/my_job-SOMERANDOMCHARS ) appears to be the original workspace path before you ran ws(). Or it could be where your pipeline file is checking out. Without seeing your code, it is hard to guess at where you are trying to put your workspace files.

Either way, if you use the WORKSPACE variable, you can get the current workspace.  Run the following pipeline code and examine the output. This should explain how this all works.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('first'){
            steps {
                ws('/tmp/foobar') {
                    sh "pwd"
                    sh 'echo New Workspace - ${WORKSPACE}' //environment variable
                    echo 'New Workspace' + WORKSPACE //groovy variable
                }
                sh "pwd"
                sh "echo Original Workspace - ${WORKSPACE}"  //interpolated groovy variable
                echo "Original Workspace - ${WORKSPACE}"       //interpolated groovy variable
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** I modified your example to be a running example on my machine to try to reproduce, but it works just fine. Does this run on your Jenkins?

```
stage('tests') {
  parallel(
    'Unit Tests': {
       node('Linux') {
         ws('/tmp/foobar') {
           def file1 = new File("${env.WORKSPACE}/package.json")
           println 'File1 is: ' + file1
           echo "${env.WORKSPACE}"
           sh 'echo $WORKSPACE/package.json'
         }
       }
    },
    'E2E Tests': {
       node('Linux') {
         ws('/tmp/baz') {
           def file2 = new File("${env.WORKSPACE}/package.json")
           println 'File2 is: ' + file2
           echo "${env.WORKSPACE}"
           sh 'echo $WORKSPACE/package.json'
         }
       }
    }
  )
}
```

Maybe the problem is not where you think it is, or maybe there is a bug in the version of Jenkins or a plugin you are using. If println of the file handle shows the correct path, then something else might be the problem.

Comment: I've added some more context as to how I'm attempting to use the workspace location.

Comment: I played with your additional detail. I can't seem to reproduce. Does this code work for you?

Comment: What if you set the ‘ws’ location to the same directory for both parallel branches?

Comment: If they are on different nodes (as you had in your example) then it works fine. If they are on the same node, the second stage gets the @2 on the directory. That is how Jenkins is designed. It cannot use the same workspace for 2 concurrent jobs. What is your reason for forcing the workspace? Generally it is best to avoid that for a few reasons. Maybe you could accomplish your goal without forcing the workspace?

Comment: They are actually running on two different nodes so writing to different physical locations so no worries there. I’ll review this a bit more and update my example if need be.

Comment: So it turns out there is `readFile()` and, even more conveniently, `readJSON()` that take into account the physical location and allows me to refer to files relative to the workspace root. Thanks for taking the time to try the various other options.